# ArcGIS Data Interopabality Extension and Exporting from Mapcom M4

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, sql-server-spatial, data-interoperability

I am exporting from Mapcom's M4 database into Geodatabase or Shapefile.

I have the ArcGIS Data Interopability extension and I was able to connect and export the Lines, Points, polys, etc.

When I was reviewing the exports, there are quite a few features that still appear in Mapcom M4 that are not being exported. The Mapcom database is hosted on SQL  Server Spatial.

I really am at a loss why this might be happening. While identifying the features in Mapcom, I cannot see any discernible difference between the ones that are exporting and the ones that are not.

I am hoping that someone else has encountered this problem exporting from Mapcom, and if they have any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that there are features in the table which don't have associated geometry?  Just rows? If you're unable to determine the difference between the exported features and the ones in Mapcom, how do you know there are features not being exported?  Is it by row count?

Comment: When I said I couldn't determine the difference, I meant when looking at them in Mapcom. I was looking for any noticeable differences between the features that exported and the features that did not. I can tell the ones that are not exported by looking at a particular area in Mapcom and ArcGIS and making comparisons.